# copy options of a select and insert into another select jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax

Hi all I have a site where if I change a select start an ajax call that return me a select.
In want to copy its option and insert into my existent select.
This is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#nation").change(function() {
        var nation_id = $(this).val();
        change_city_by_nation(nation_id);
    });

    function change_city_by_nation(nation_id){
            var site_url_city ="<?php echo(site_url('/backend/city/get_city_by_nation_id')); ?>";
            $.ajax({   
                url: site_url_city, 
                async: false,
                type: "POST", 
                data: "nation_id="+nation_id, 
                dataType: "html", 

                success: function(data) {
                    $('#city').html(data);
                    $('#city').prepend("<option value='0' selected='selected'>All city</option>");

                }
             });
        }
});

 <select name="nation" id="nation" style="width:180px;" >
     <option value="2">Nation2</option>
     <option value="3">Nation3</option>
</select>
<select name="city" id="city" style="width:180px;" >
     <option value="0">All city</option>
</select>
```

data alert is that:

```
<select name="citylist">
<option value="39">Adelaide</option>
<option value="43">Alice Springs</option>
<option value="44">Brisbane</option>
<option value="45">Cairns</option>
<option value="36">Canberra</option>
<option value="31">Darwin</option>
<option value="37">Gold Coast</option>
<option value="32">Margaret River - Regione dei Vini</option>
<option value="40">Melbourne</option>
<option value="41">Palm Cove</option>
<option value="35">Perth</option>
<option value="42">Port Douglas</option>
<option value="33">Sydney</option>
<option value="34">Tasmania</option>
<option value="38">Townsville</option>
</select>
```

How can I copy the option that return me from data into the success function into the  select city?
because with my way I put a select into another select.
i can't change the result from ajax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to filter your data response so this [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) 
so first filter your data then append your options:

```
success: function(data) {
                    $('#city').html($(data).filter('option'));
                    $('#city').prepend("<option value='0' selected='selected'>All city</option>");

                }
```

Comment: No it doesn't work, this code insert directly the select tag inside the select city. Is a select inside another select, I want to copy only the options

Comment: @AlessandroMinoccheri sorry, try again with 'option' instead of 'select'.